# Error 404 bad request when it tried to store a form in my database

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to store a form in my database but I am getting this error:

Error `POST http://localhost:5090/api/inventory/create/ 400 (Bad Request)`

The list method works correctly but when trying to register I have this problem

I have structured the code as follows

**Fronted:**

React and Axios

**Backend:**

.Net 6 web api

## Frontend:

##### Inventory View:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import Console from "../components/Console";
import { InventoryCreate } from "../services/inventory/InventoryDataService";

const PageInventoryCreate = function () {
  const [iventory_state, setIventory_state] = useState({
    name: "",
    code: "",
    location: "",
  });

  const { name, code, location } = iventory_state;

  const handleInputChange = function (e) {
    setIventory_state({
      ...iventory_state,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSumit = function (e, iventory_state) {
    e.preventDefault();
    InventoryCreate(iventory_state);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Console stateName={iventory_state} />
      <h1>Create</h1>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="nombre"
          name="name"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={name}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="codigo"
          name="code"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={code}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Ubicacion"
          name="location"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={location}
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSumit}>
          Crear
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
export default PageInventoryCreate;
```

#### Axios Services

```js
import axios from "axios";

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5090/api/",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  },
});
export default http;
```

##### Http request to controller Inventories

```js
import http from "../http-server";

export async function getAllInventories() {
  try {
    const response = await http.get("/inventory/list/");
    const result = response.data;
    // console.log(result);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export async function InventoryCreate(data) {
  try {
    const response = await http.post(`/inventory/create/`, data);
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

## Backend

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using API.Data;
using API.Models;
using API.Dtos;
using AutoMapper;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/inventory/")]
    public class InventoryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;
        public InventoryController(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext, IMapper map)
        {
            db = applicationDbContext;
            mapper = map;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("list/")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<DtoInventory>>> GetAll()
        {
            IQueryable<Inventory> queryset = from inv in db.Iventories
                                             select inv;
            List<Inventory> inventory_list = await queryset.ToListAsync();
            List<DtoInventory> dto = mapper.Map<List<DtoInventory>>(inventory_list);
            return dto;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("create/")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromForm] Inventory inventory)
        {
            inventory.created_date = DateTime.Now;
            db.Add(inventory);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok("Registro exitoso!");
            // return CreatedAtRoute("GetInventory", new { id = inventory.inventory_id, }, inventory);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `Bad Request` usually means the data you've POSTed is bad. unfortunately, you didn't _share_ that data (POST body), _or_ the code for `Inventory`. without that information, i don't think there's much we can do.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann you mean the information that I am sent in the form?
If so, I just uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i described. but please, in the future, provide all text-based information as _text_, not as screenshot...  that being said: try `[FromBody]` instead of `[FromForm]` - if i recall correctly, FromForm doesn't accept JSON

Comment: Error changed to `Error: Request failed with status code 415`
I am looking for the reason for this error, according to content-type, but I have already defined it in my axios service, in line 5 `headers: { "Content-type": "application/json", }`

Comment: Can you share the data and check the data type which you passed to Create?

Comment: I already detected the problem I had (or so I think) I needed to transform the data from js to json before sending the data as parameters to the axios post function `let body_request = JSON.stringify(iventory_state);`
Thanks!! 
Do I have to delete this publication or how do I close it?